# 'props' of undefined inside map closure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`. I need to my `Li` component to receive `props`. I'm using styled-component by the way.

```
const Li = styled.li`
  border-top: 0 none;
`;

class Popular extends Component {
    render() {
        var languages = ['All', 'Javascript', 'Java', 'Python'];
        return (
            <ul className='list-group'>
                {languages.map(function(lang){
                    return (
                        <Li className={`list-group-item p-2 ${this.props.className}`}>
                            {lang}
                        </Li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default Popular;
```

Comment: I think your problem might be that `languages.map(function(lang)` should be `languages.map((lang) => )`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the callback of `languages.map` to the `popular` class. You can either use arrow function like this

```
{languages.map((lang) => {
```

or just pass `this` as the second argument of map function like this

```
{languages.map(function(lang){
       ...
}, this)}
```

or you can bind it using `bind` function like this

```
{languages.map((function(lang){
       ...
}).bind(this))}
```

Comment: There is no need to call `.bind`, you can just pass `this` as second argument to `.map`: `languages.map(function(lang){...}, this);`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, i forgot that. Updated. Thanx